# Is it possible to attach file to HTTPS request using AWS Distributed Load Testing tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-testing

I am currently using AWS's Elastic Beanstalk for some of my applications. I noticed the configuration isn't optimal, so I'm working on performance tuning.

To assess the performance, I initially used Apache JMeter locally. However, I could only achieve around 450 RPS, which is far below the expected peak load of my applications.

I then explored the [AWS Distributed Load Testing Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/) from the AWS Solutions Library. It allowed me to reach the desired RPS, but I've encountered a challenge:

One of my apps requires an HTTPS request with a `P3IC` file attachment. While I was able to configure this on my local JMeter setup, I'm struggling to do so with the AWS tool.

The AWS tool offers two modes:

Manual configuration on the dashboard – This mode doesn't seem to have an option for file attachment.
Uploading a JMeter (`.jmx`) test plan – My local test plan works perfectly, but the file path for the `P3IC` attachment points to a local directory. When I run the test in AWS, it understandably can't locate the file. I tried zipping the `.jmx` and `P3IC` file together, but the path remains local, causing AWS to fail to find the file.
I've reached a roadblock and would be grateful for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Without knowing the full details of this tool, have you tried uploading the file to S3 and then either using an https:// link to it, possible pre-signed, or alternatively an s3:// link within the test plan!?

Comment: Looking at the code that is probably not supported, but following https://github.com/aws-solutions/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/blob/f40bb264e1ba8b5f5b2f5f22cae978c743c615e5/deployment/ecr/distributed-load-testing-on-aws-load-tester/load-test.sh#L27 it should be possible to use a zip file with the jmx and P3IC in it - did you just place both file top level in the zip and what did the path to the P3IC file then look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/considerations.html):

> If you have JMeter input files, you can zip the input files together with the JMeter script. You can choose the zip file when you create a test scenario.

So package your file(s) into a zip archive and upload with the .jmx test script and that would be it.

Just avoid using absolute paths and JMeter should pick the file up. More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I added the file path as just the file's name in the .jmx test plan (e.g. Path: testfile.txt, Parameter Name: dataFile, MIME type: XYZ). I packaged the .jmx and the file to attach into a ZIP, uploaded that to the AWS tool and it works fine.